What lead Shri Madhusudhan Saraswati to accept Advaita Vedanta?
Shri Madhusudhan Saraswati, a Vaishnava by birth was a great devotee of Lord Krishna. He once went out to meet Chaitanya Mahaprabhu but en route switched over to Advaita Vedanta. What happen during his journey that lead him to change his entire life?
